# How do I scrape information in this table using R?

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to scrape the following web page: https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/sweden/stockholm/historic?month=3&year=2020
I am interested in the table at the end, below "Stockholm Weather History for..."

With the submitted code I am able to get the information for the 1st in the month, but I don't understand how to get it for the rest of the days. If I change the date in the drop-down list the url address doesn't change.
How can I scrape that table for all days of the month?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", port=4234L, chromever ="85.0.4183.83")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/sweden/stockholm/historic?month=3&year=2020")
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using="class name", value="sticky-wr")
s<-webElems[[1]]$getElementText()
s<-as.character(s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. That seems to be a faster way to get the table for the 1st day in a month. But my problem is getting all the other days. Is that possible with the method you use? I am a beginner at this so I don't really understand what your code is doing and if it's possible to use it for other days

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can extract the table with `rvest` itself and don't need `Rselenium` here. Although, the table might require some cleaning.

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/sweden/stockholm/historic?month=3&year=2020'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[3]] %>% 
  setNames(.[1, ]) -> tmp

tmp[-c(1, nrow(tmp)), ]

#             Time  Temp                    Weather    Wind   Humidity Barometer Visibility
#2  0:20.Aha 01 Mac  2 °C Light rain. Mostly cloudy. 20 km/h ↑      93%  988 mbar       5 km
#3            0:50.  2 °C       Drizzle. Low clouds. 13 km/h ↑      93%  988 mbar        N/A
#4            1:20.  2 °C       Drizzle. Low clouds. 15 km/h ↑     100%  987 mbar       9 km
#5            1:50.  2 °C       Drizzle. Low clouds. 15 km/h ↑     100%  987 mbar       8 km
#6            2:20.  2 °C    Light rain. Low clouds. 19 km/h ↑     100%  986 mbar       6 km
#7            2:50.  2 °C    Light rain. Low clouds. 19 km/h ↑     100%  985 mbar       4 km
#...
```